# Compression Action Filter ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, filter, compression, asp.net-core

I need to create Compression Action Filter using ASP.NET Core

I found some examples for MVC 5 like:

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute   {

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

    var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

    encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

    if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
        response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
    else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
}
```

But when I tried to use it with

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
```

It didn't work at all:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

namespace App.Filterss
{
    public class CompressionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;

            string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
            {
                response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                response.Body = new GZipStream(response.Body, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
            {
                response.Headers.Add("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Body = new DeflateStream(response.Body, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just get 200 http responce with no content at all.

Can anybody tip me how to perform compressing using filter?

Comment: You are not calling the base method: `base.OnActionExecuted(context);`

Comment: It doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is a new feature at ASP.net Core 1.1.

This is the packages you will need.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression/

here is some official microsoft video showing how to use it:
https://youtu.be/IfLg6LQCl-Y?t=223

some background information:
https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/34

Code:

Project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...,
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "1.0.0"
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
...
//Add Middleware
app.UseResponseCompression();

....
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//Configure Compression level
services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

//Add Response compression services
services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [rynowak](https://github.com/rynowak)'s answer on an [GitHib issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/487#issuecomment-97695667) for ASP.NET Core 1.0

> 1). If you're on IIS why not just use dynamic compression at the
>   server level?
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
>
> 2). Our default streams are not intended to be read. By default we do
>   some buffering in these streams, but we don't buffer the whole
>   response because that would use an awful lot of memory. Once the
>   amount of data we're willing to buffer has been written, it goes out
>   on the wire and we don't store it any more. There are some techniques
>   to enable buffering, and one of them is to replace the stream.
>
> 3). If you want to mess with the response stream for an MVC action (or
>   all MVC actions), the right filter stage is a result filter (
>   IResultFilter  or  IAsyncResultFilter ).
>
> Thing of it this way, calling  View()  in your controller is creating
>   an  IActionResult , which will be executed by MVC later, it's not
>   actually executing the view inline, and that's why messing with the
>   stream in that phase doesn't do what you want.
>
> Result Filters actually surround the execution of the view code.
>
> 4). If you want to mess with the response stream for your whole
>   application and don't want to/can't use gzip support provided by your
>   server, then middleware is a good choice. (Compare to filters, which
>   allow you to scope to Controller/Action).
>
> If you still having issues with the middleware approach used above:
>   have you tried setting a break point in the action in question to make
>   sure it's actually hit? have you removed your action filter code
>   (which wouldn't do what you want)?

Comment: Great! Thank you for your post!

Comment: I am interested not in adding compression itself (of course I can configure IIS server), but in information about general possibility of creating such a filter.

And this possibility is still unclear. This post claims: (point 3) "If you want to mess with the response stream for an MVC action (or all MVC actions), the right filter stage is a result filter ( IResultFilter or IAsyncResultFilter )" 

But I still failed to add commpression from result filter.

Comment: So as far as I am concern in asp core I can't read responce body at all and the whole feature for switching on and off responce compression in filter becomes disabled since now?

Comment: @OlgaKozlova: In your example above you are hooking into the action filter (overriding `OnActionExecuting`). To hook into the result, you need to override `OnResultExecuting` instead. rynowak's 2nd option (replacing streams) point refers to ben adams suggestion of adding a middleware, which replaces the stream which works around the auto-flushing of the stream. But by doing so you can't set it on a per controler base, it's application wide